# Why is the reaction between calcium oxide and silicon dioxide neutralization?

Tags: acid-base, salt

I get that calcium oxide is a basic oxide and silicon dioxide is acidic. However by definition, neutralization is "when an acid and a base react to form water and a salt and involves the combination of $\ce{H+}$ ions and $\ce{OH-}$ ions to generate water". Yet I don't see any water as a product when calcium silicate is formed.

$$\ce{CaO(s) + SiO2(s)-> CaSiO3(l)}$$

So since water is not a product, how can it be considered neutralization? Or if it isn't neutralization, what sort of reaction is it?

Comment: acid base reaction does not necessary involve water formation. I will another example: HCl (gas)+ NH3(gas) what do they form- a solid salt in gas phase.

Comment: The statement that "neutralization is the reaction of an acid and a base producing a salt plus water" is a concept developed in the 19th century. The reaction of $\ce{CaO + SiO2}$ is not really a neutralization. It is a synthesis.

Comment: It's only an acid base reaction according to [Lux–Flood definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid%E2%80%93base_reaction#Lux%E2%80%93Flood_definition)

Comment: According to wikipedia, neutralisation is just a rxn btw acids and bases/alkali; it doesn't talk about the production of water. CaO is a basic oxide while SiO2 is an acidic oxide, hence it is similar to acids & bases reacting i.e. neutralisation.